# Should a javascript web application use another server side language?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, web-applications, server-side

I want to create a web application.  I do a lot of java and am not overly impressed with the web application frameworks available.

I was thinking about using another server side language like php but I don't want the learning curve.

This brings me to javascript.  Can and should I perform all of the server side calls with ajax?  I have a service oriented architecture available and can access all the data I need.

Is it more advantageous to use a server side language in conjunction with javascript to build a robust web application?  Is it preferable to use pure javascript and make ajax calls to my web services?

Comment: LOL, learning curve and PHP in the same sentence. If you know Java, just start drinking heavily and PHP will make perfect sense. OR, learn Ruby on Rails. That one does have a bit of a curve, but it's very worthwhile.

Comment: What kind of services do you have that you can use?  SOAP?  Restful services, returning XML or JSON?  Binary blobs?  Do you control the services, or someone else?

Comment: I would learn C# and .NET, RoR or Python before I touched Java or PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **Can and should I perform all of the server side calls with ajax?**

Yes. you can perform all of the server side calls with AJAX. Even now a days a lot of single page apps are emerging which make heavy use of AJAX and Javascript MVC to communicate with server. Even some of the javascript frameworks provide REST support inbuilt(e.g. - **Backbone JS**).
 But having said that, *you should consider having fallback mechanisms for AJAX calls*. So, if user has turned off the javascript he should be navigated to appropriate page. (Again this depends on your choice of whether to support nonJS or not)

### **Is it more advantageous to use a server side language in conjunction with javascript to build a robust web application?**

The advantages for using javscript depend on your test case and mainly the audience for your service. But it is definitely more "***adventurous***" to move towards asynchronous communication, but only when you use it in a structured way. I suggest to go with any of the MVC framework on Javascript side for this.

### **Is it preferable to use pure javascript and make ajax calls to my web services?**

Again preferance depends on the use case scenario of your web service. There is no harm in using javascript as such. The only thing is you should be little aware about security of the javascript calls you are making.

Answer (score 1):

You can, but the question is should you? It's been recommended to fallback gracefully for the people with JavaScript disabled since the beginning, but some big services and sites don't seem to mind anymore. You can't open Facebook, for example, without JavaScript enabled.

That isn't to say you should do it. You've got to justify it by making the experience even better. Make sure its navigation works perfectly and you utilize the history correctly.

A client side application also has to deal with browser differences on a whole new level. This is of course made easier with frameworks such as jQuery, but you will notice the difference between the browsers.

Answer (score 0):

When you build a web application solely with Javascript, you are giving entirely all loads and processes to the client. Well technically the server still does some work, since you're going to use ajax calls, yet performance-wise considering low-end PCs or average mobile devices, they'll be having a hard time loading up your web app..

In the case of using PHP and Javascript together, you are given such flexibility to give your web app more performance, since the client and server are sharing loads and processes with each other.. And of course using PHP will give you better tools to access your site's database easily, MySQL in this case ..